# Backup and restore without custom recovery?

Tags: backup, restore, stock-android, nandroid

Can I backup and restore without a custom recovery if I have a nandroid backup? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Stock recovery's don't offer this feature, you would need a custom recovery to backup and restore.